# How can I get result on all dates?

Tags: sql, date, phpmyadmin

On this query, I only get values on the days where WET>=6. How can I get ´0´ on these days?

```
SELECT
DATE(DTM) AS 'Dia',
CASE
WHEN (AVG(TMP)<13 OR COUNT(WET)=0) THEN '0'
WHEN ((AVG(TMP)>=13 AND AVG(TMP)<17) AND (COUNT(TMP)/4>=0 AND COUNT(TMP)/4<6)) THEN '0'
WHEN ((AVG(TMP)>=13 AND AVG(TMP)<17) AND (COUNT(TMP)/4>=6 AND COUNT(TMP)/4<15)) THEN '1'
WHEN ((AVG(TMP)>=13 AND AVG(TMP)<17) AND (COUNT(TMP)/4>=15 AND COUNT(TMP)/4<20)) THEN '2'
WHEN ((AVG(TMP)>=13 AND AVG(TMP)<17) AND (COUNT(TMP)/4>=20)) THEN '3'
END
AS 'DSV TOMCAST'
FROM dados_meteo
WHERE WET>=6/* AND POM='[VARIABLE]'*/
GROUP BY DATE(DTM)
```

Comment: 0 is the value of WET? Is this you wanna get?

Comment: o is the value that I wanna get when there are no records with WET above 6.

Comment: You wanna return 0 for a column that have a Date, in this case Dia? 0 refers to what field?

Comment: Is not a "base" field. It is built by the Query. It is a Date classification

Comment: so you have a table named dados_meteo that has a date field and then some other fields about the weather?  you want to run a query that returns EVERY date and for every date you want your case statement to do it's thing when WET>6 and put zero for your case statement results if there is no record for that date?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it now, you wanna return a default value when there's no record with `WET >= 6`. You can accomplish this with the technique described here:

[Oracle: Get a query to always return exactly one row, even when there's no data to be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682821/oracle-get-a-query-to-always-return-exactly-one-row-even-when-theres-no-data-t/4683045#4683045)

Comment: Thank you. But with this solution I will have the average temperature of the hours where WET=0 and I only want where the WET>6

Comment: Sorry. Not working. It's still missing a day when there no records with WET >6