# How to check if there exist only one record for a certain Id

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, distinct

How to check if there exist only one record for a certain Id

I have two tables called `Tbl_Company` and `Tbl_Employee`
I am fetching employees as follows-

```
SELECT DISTINCT emp.employee_id
FROM Tbl_Company comp
           , Tbl_Employee emp
WHERE 
           emp.company_id = comp.company_id 
           AND emp.company_id = 1234;
```

This query returns exactly one value.
How can I make sure that above query returns exacly one value for any comany_id I enter.

I tried using solutions given in  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682821/oracle-get-a-query-to-always-return-exactly-one-row-even-when-theres-no-data) post with no success.
Is there any simpler way to do this.

Comment: which row for each company would you want to return?

Comment: I want to get employee_Id and want to make sure there should be only one employee_id for a company_id

Comment: Each of your companies has only a single employee? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AaronDigulla:  this is just an example

Comment: so if oyu want to see which companies have more than 1 employee you don't want a distinct but a COUNT instead

Comment: What do you want to happen when there are several employees? Should the query fail? Return more than a single row? Select a one of the employees at random? ... oh wait, Microsoft. Random, of course! With a 12.7436348% chance of blue screen. Silly me.

Comment: @AaronDigulla The query should fail if there are multiple results for a company_id

Comment: @microsoft, it makes no sense for the query to "fail", you can't make a query fail just because you don't like the data. Surely you would want to know of data which is against your business rules so you can fix it

Comment: @davegreen100 I may going to use this query multiple times at multiple place even as a **SUBQUERY**. Also, this is just a sample query I have written to get the solution original one is huge.

Comment: i would write a query to COUNT the number of employees per company (so a GROUP BY on company), you could also use HAVING > 1 to identify those which need action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by using ans by `@davegreen100` in comment

```
SELECT comp.companyid, count(distinct emp.employee_id), 
FROM Tbl_Company comp
           , Tbl_Employee emp
WHERE 
           emp.company_id = comp.company_id 
           AND emp.company_id = 1234
GROUP BY comp.companyid
```

This will give me the count of employees per company

Comment: your COUNT(DISTINCT) is incorrect, it should be counting the employee_id and not the companyid

Comment: ... or you could use count(*)

Comment: "comp.employeeId" -- employeeid is a column in the company table?

Answer (score 0):

this would return one row per company

```
SELECT comp.companyid, max(emp.employee_id) lastEmployeeID
FROM Tbl_Company comp
           , Tbl_Employee emp
WHERE 
           emp.company_id = comp.company_id 
           AND emp.company_id = 1234
GROUP BY comp.companyid
```

Comment: Please explain what you did.

Comment: the original query selected a DISTINCT id from all the companies, i have shown one id for each company by including the company id in the select and the group by. I struggle to see a good reason for wanting the query.

Answer (score 0):

the following query is simple and flexible. it will return a list of all employees which are alone in their companies (returned with full employee information).

you can check if a defined company has one lonely employee by enable condition about company or you can check if employee is a lonely employee by enabling employee condition.

```
SELECT emp.*
FROM Tbl_Company comp
           /*, Tbl_Employee emp*/
WHERE (emp.company_id , 1) in (select t.company_id, count(t.employee_id) from Tbl_Company t )
  --AND emp.company_id = 1111 /*filter conditions on company_id*/
  --AND emp.employee_id = 1234/*filter conditions on employee_id*/;
```