# I need a query that returns 0 when no results are found, ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I don't know what's happening here, I try this:
[image]

But the result never returns 0, what's I doing wrong?
EDIT:

all rows in table

| num | id | perc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | -20 |
| 3 | 19 | -10 |
| 3 | 58 | -15 |
| 3 | 88 | -50 |
| 3 | 351 | -30 |
| 3 | 602 | -25 |

I use "WHERE i.ID = '221'" because I need returns 0 when not exists row with id 221 in table.

Comment: It never makes it to the last when, because of the first one.  As soon as a when returns true, the case statement is exited.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: When you're asking for help, you’ll get more/better answers if you [don’t post screenshots or photos](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Cut & paste the text directly into the message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

See also http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle: Get a query to always return exactly one row, even when there's no data to be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682821/oracle-get-a-query-to-always-return-exactly-one-row-even-when-theres-no-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, the CASE statement doesn't fall through - it breaks/exits on the first successful test. Therefore, your first two tests:

```
WHEN (i.id IS NULL) THEN..
WHEN (i.id IS NOT NULL) THEN..
```

Cover 100% of all possible cases. A value is either NULL or NOT NULL, so one of these two will be true and the remainder of your tests will never be evaluated. I think you probably need separate columns to do the various tests you want. At least one column for nullability and one column for length and whatever else you need.

As for the next expression, you have `NVL(i.id,0)` , but in your WHERE clause you are asking for `id = '221'`. Since you only get back values 221, none of the rows will have a NULL value in the id column, so NVL will not produce a 0.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be something like below:

```
with qt as (
--- here comes your query returning the desired result if found

)
select test
from qt
union all
select 0 --- this produces 0 when your query returns  no rows
from dual where not exists (select 1 from qt)
```